# node js express routing request get called twice

Tags: node.js

I'm building an app with Nodejs and when a page load the get request get called twice. Here is the request for the index page.

Any idea why this is happening and how to fix it?

```
router.get("/",(req,res)=>{ 
    res.render("index",{csrfToken: req.csrfToken()}); 
});
```